# How to set up a Canon MF8000 series (i-SENSYS MF8030) multifunctional on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, scanner

We've got a Canon i-SENSYS MF8030 multifunctional (printer + scanner) an our new office, everybody are happy with it using Windows 7 but I want to be able to print from (and scan to if possible) my Ubuntu (XUbuntu actually) system.

I've tried to set it up as a generic PCL laser printer but that doesn't work.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit system

1. Download Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V250_uk_EN.tar.gz
2. Unpack Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V250_uk_EN.tar.gz
3. Skip if deb files available

   ```
   sudo alien -d cndrvcups-common-2.50-1.x86_64.rpm
   sudo alien -d cndrvcups-ufr2-uk-2.50-1.x86_64.rpm 
   ls
   ```

   You should then have these 2 files:

   ```
   cndrvcups-common_2.50-2_amd64.deb
   cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_2.50-2_amd64.deb
   ```
4. With deb files start here:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib64
   sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_2.50-2_amd64.deb 
   sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_2.50-2_amd64.deb 
   sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
   sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
   sudo gedit /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.cupsd
   ```

   Add:

   ```
   /usr/lib64/cups/backend/cnusb Uxr,
   /usr/lib64/cups/filter/pstoufr2cpca Uxr,
   sudo service cups restart
   ```

   Then search for network printer, select Dnssd printer Canon MF8300.

Comment: You should include the download link.

Comment: Brilliant, this worked like a charm for my MF3010. First time I got this thing to print in Linux.

Comment: Says "Missing print filter for printer..."

Comment: Are you sure you've quoted `usr.sbin.cupsd` correctly and both the commas at the lines ends and the last line "sudo service cups restart" are to be put in the file? I know nothing about apparmor.

Answer (score 0):

To add on what @Markus B wrote:

If you are trying to set this up on a server you may have to change the configuration files a little bit more.

Open the file /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

In area:

```
<Location />

<Location /admin>

<Location /admin/conf>
```

Add the following line :

```
Allow all
```

Also comment out the other lines with `Listen` and replace with `Port 631  # Listen on port 631 on all interfaces`

More info at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html